# Are setters mandatory in extbase models?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am following this documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/10.4/en-us/5-Domain/2-implementing-the-domain-model.html

The 'Organization' model defines setters and a method "addContact"

```php
     /**
     * Adds a contact to the organization
     *
     * @param Person The contact to be added
     * @return void
     */
    public function addContact(Person $contact)
    {
       $this->contacts->attach($contact);
    }
```

I created an extbase model myself, which requires records from an objectstorage. But i figured it out, that I could render records from an objectstorage in fluid, without defining "add{property}" and "set{property} methods. What are the purpose of these methods? When and where are they called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setter methods (and adder for ObjectStorages) are not needed by the framework.  I'd recommend not adding them if you do not have the use case of setting a value programmatically.

Generally speaking you should not add code that you dont need.

Extbase itself will use reflection to gather and set properties that match database columns.

Answer (score 0):

Setters are for fields that have a representation in the database.
You can add more properties to the models which are i.e. calculated or get the values somewhere else from that don't have setter methods.
Those properties you can access in fluid templates as long as they have also a declaration in the model.

Concerning the method `addContact` that's one property with probably 4 methods:

- getContact (is singular but can have several)
- setContact (is singular but can have several)
- addContact (adds one contact to the `$contact`)
- removeContact (removes one contact from the `$contact`)

So this property is still connected / related to the database, just that it's a foreign table as it's foreign model too.
`$contact` in your case is likely of type `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage` which is like an array iterable but just as object.

Comment: Thanks, but i i didn't understand, why it works only with "getContact". I left out the methods "setContact", "addContact" and "removeContact". "getContact" still delivered the contacts i defined in the backend.

Comment: Without `setContact` your Contact might be empty even if you have some data in the database. I'm not sure why it worked like you described.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the data is still cached or something. But I still get the correct data from the database without 'setContact' and 'addContact' in TYPO3 10.4.30

Comment: ok, it's not advisable to use the code without these methods, no matter if you get the data